# SQL get rows being not in JOIN

Tags: mysql, sql, database, join, select

I have three tables :

field:

| f_id | f_start | f_end |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 10 | 20 |
| 2 | 15 | 25 |
| 3 | 5 | 10 |

person :

| p_id | p_name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Roger |
| 2 | John |
| 3 | Alicia |
| 4 | Patrick |
| 5 | Bob |
| 6 | Carlos |
| 7 | Mandy |

affect :

| id | fk_field | fk_person |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | 1 |
| 2 | 1 | 2 |
| 3 | 3 | 3 |

With this query :

```
SELECT p.p_name, f.f_start, f.f_end
FROM person p
INNER JOIN affect a ON a.fk_person = p.p_id
INNER JOIN field f ON f.f_id = a.fk_field
WHERE f.f_end < 21 AND f.f_start > 7;
```

I'm getting this result :

| p_name | f_start | f_end |
| --- | --- | --- |
| John | 10 | 20 |

But I would like to have the persons who are not in affect too, meaning that they are available. It includes that there will be empty values like this :

| p_name | f_start | f_end |
| --- | --- | --- |
| John | 10 | 20 |
| Patrick |  |  |
| Bob |  |  |
| Carlos |  |  |
| Mandy |  |  |

Would that be possible ? thanks

Comment: Try `left join` see: https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-left-join.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `LEFT JOIN` instead of `INNER JOIN` and also need to specify the condition in the `LEFT JOIN` itself. The condition in `WHERE` clause is given to get your expected result. I.e. to include person which either matches with the *field* table or doesn't available in the *affect* table:

```
SELECT p.p_name, f.f_start, f.f_end
FROM person p
LEFT JOIN affect a ON a.fk_person = p.p_id
LEFT JOIN field f ON f.f_id = a.fk_field AND f.f_end < 21 AND f.f_start > 7
WHERE f.f_id IS NOT NULL
 OR a.id IS NULL
```

Output:

| p_name | f_start | f_end |
| --- | --- | --- |
| John | 10 | 20 |
| Patrick |  |  |
| Bob |  |  |
| Carlos |  |  |
| Mandy |  |  |

See this [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.5&fiddle=6abd4e0116f0f521c7ce15ff47508a07)

Answer (score 0):

Use a left join:

````
    FROM person p
    LEFT JOIN affect a ON a.fk_person = p.p_id
    INNER JOIN field f ON f.f_id = a.fk_field
    WHERE f.f_end < 21 AND f.f_start > 7; ```
````

Comment: Yes but there is a 'WHERE' so the result will be the same ? Shouldn't a 'JOIN' be after the 'WHERE' ? I'm new to SQL sorry

Comment: No the where belongs after the JOIN statements. The results should be like you want them to.